# javascript jquery rotate plugin not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

index.html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/Randomitem/index.js"></script>
```

jQueryRotateCompressed.js
Some code for the plugin.

```
(function (k) {
  for (
    var d,
      f,
      l = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].style,
      h = [
        "transformProperty",
        "WebkitTransform",
        "OTransform",
        "msTransform",
        "MozTransform",
      ],
      g = 0;
    g < h.length;
    g++
  )
    void 0 !== l[h[g]] && (d = h[g]);
  d &&
    ((f = d.replace(/[tT]ransform/, "TransformOrigin")),
    "T" == f[0] && (f[0] = "t"));
  eval('IE = "v"=="\v"');
  jQuery.fn.extend({
    rotate: function (a) {
      if (0 !== this.length && "undefined" != typeof a) {
        "number" == typeof a && (a = { angle: a });
        for (var b = [], c = 0, d = this.length; c < d; c++) {
          var e = this.get(c);
          if (e.Wilq32 && e.Wilq32.PhotoEffect)
            e.Wilq32.PhotoEffect._handleRotation(a);
          else {
            var f = k.extend(!0, {}, a),
              e = new Wilq32.PhotoEffect(e, f)._rootObj;
            b.push(k(e));
          }
        }
        return b;
      }
    },
```

js/Randomitem/index.js

```
  $('#capsule'+i).rotate({
                duration:1280*i,
                angle: 0, 
                animateTo:880
            });
```

Error message $(...).rotate is not a function
I think I applied the plug-in normally. But why do they say rotate doesn't exist?
Help me!

Answer (score 0):

its because you are missing "https:" in your jquery CDN, it's pretty much saying "$" does not exist but the error is kind of misleading.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

change it to

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```